# Clojure Enlive: Applying snippet on a list

Tags: html, clojure, enlive

I am trying to define an enlive template for a html table, that shows data from a map.
`template-div` for this example is right [here](https://gist.github.com/vesnap/5329dc1089d2981e6a0c). Dummy content that for the cells in the template is [here](https://gist.github.com/vesnap/ed545f77d53d5bc14f19).

`defsnippet` for cell value and `deftemplate` are defined as:

```
(require '[net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html])

(html/defsnippet value-cell (template-div) [:div.Row :div.Cell] [value]
          (html/content value))
```

However, when I try the snippet

```
(value-cell (mapv vals (:event-data dummy-content)))
```

All the values are in one tag like this

```
({:tag :div, :attrs {:class "Cell"}, 
:content ("end time 1" "date 1" "event name 1" "start time 1"  "performer 1" "end time 2" "date 2" "event name 2" "start time 2" "performer 2")})
```

And I need every item from a list to be a value in the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a list of values to value-cell, so value-cell should look something like:

```
(html/defsnippet value-cell (template-div)
  [:div.Row :div.Cell]
  [values]
  (html/clone-for [value values]
                  (html/content value)))
```

Comment: yes this is it, I was playing with clone-for but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Oh, and also, how to put the data from each map into separate row, because this (html/deftemplate mshp (index) [cont]
               [:div.Row] 
              (html/content (map value-cell (mapv vals (:event-data dummy-content))))) doesn't work?

Comment: it is the same problem. What you are telling enlive is "change the content of :div.Row for ...". What you want to tell it is "create one like :div.Row for each", which would translate for a clone-for

Comment: yes, but, how to apply clone-for on every map, I need clone-for for cell, and then clone-for for row?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want one :div.Row per entry on the map, not one :div.Cell per entry. If this is the case, what you want to clone is the whole :div.Row, so your value-cell snippet should be called, `value-row` and be something like (... [:div.Row] [event-data] (clone-for [[k v] event-data] [:div.Cell] (content v)))

Comment: Ok, this should be it (html/defsnippet  value-row3 (template-div) 
                 [:div.Row] [event-data] (html/clone-for [vs event-data] [:div.Cell]
                                                         (html/clone-for [v vs] (html/content v)))) and then the call is like this (value-row3 (mapv vals (:event-data dummy-content)))

Comment: this works fine as a snippet, but now I'm having trouble with calling a template, (html/deftemplate mshp (index) [cont]
               [:div.Title] (html/content (:title cont))
               [:div.Heading] 
               (html/content (for [c (keys (first (:event-data cont)))] (header-cell (name c)))) [:div.Row] (value-row (mapv vals (:event-data cont)))), and a call (print (apply str (mshp  dummy-content))) gives me this error ClassCastException clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  net.cgrand.enlive-html/transform-loc (enlive_html.clj:426)

Comment: this is template that works, (html/deftemplate mshp (index) [cont]
               [:div.Title] (html/content (:title cont))
               [:div.Heading] 
               (html/content (for [c (keys (first (:event-data cont)))] (header-cell (name c)))) [:div.Row] (html/content (value-row (mapv vals (:event-data cont))))), and a call to the template (print (apply str (mshp  dummy-content)))